# Why non-conditional JSX doesn't works after setting state value from another variable

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, jsx

This is the code where I set the values and update after an api call

```
function Expense() {
  const [details, setDetails] = useState({});
  const [login, setLogin] = useState(false);
  const [expyear, setExpyear] = useState();


  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      (//Api call...)
        .then((res) => {
          const details = res.data[0];
          // Also when I do setDetails(res.data[0]) the non-conditional render works fine but I want to set some value immediately after the Api call
          setDetails(details);
          setLogin(true);
          setExpyear(details.year);
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, []);
```

But when I try to render the following JSX, that gives an error as `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Fullname')` also when I log props {details} in LastData, is shows empty object

```
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <LastData details={details} />
        {details.Fullname}
        {expyear}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Only untill I change it to conditional rendering, it works fine

```
  return login ? (
    <div>
      <div>
        <LastData details={details} />
        {details.Fullname}
        {expyear}
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div>Hello</div>
  );
}
```

I need to know why I have to put a condition to render the JSX and why does it render non-conditionally after setting direct api value to state?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because `setState` is asynchronous operation, and initial value of `details` state is empty object (that leads to `details.Fullname === undefined` at initial render).
Only when this group of state settings are done:

```
setDetails(details);
setLogin(true);
setExpyear(details.year);
```

and login set to true you can see all rest data rendered.

You can also add initial state to `details` instead of empty object set some data for used fields, for example `useState({FullName: ""})`.
At first render you will have empty string and when state updates, you 'll get your fetched `FullName` value.

Comment: I can set the state value for name but when I pass `details` as a prop, it remains undefined till I add `login ? ...`

Comment: Async operations are the reason why loaders and skeletons are added to rendered component conditionally. For example instead of `<div>Hello</div>` add loader/spinner. You can't render value untill it is fetched and component is updated.